# Access internet through 3G USB modem (ppp0) with wlan0 and eth0

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and a Huawei 3G USB modem. I would like to be able to connect to the internet using the eth0 *and* wlan0 interface, but all I was able to achieve is to connect via one or the other interface, but not both.

I have setup the configuration to dial into the cell provider, as well as all the steps needed to configure a static ip address and doing all the configuration with the NAT as described in this post: https://www.benfreke.org/201712/raspberry-pi-3g-4g-hotspot/ (scroll to "CREATING A WIFI HOTSPOT"). However, this gives me access to access the internet through the Pi's wireless chip, but I have no way to access the internet through a wired connection using the ethernet (eth0). I would like to be able to do *both*, access through wlan0 but also when connecting an internet cable to the Pi. How can I achieve this? I can setup accessing the internet through the eth0 network, by simply replacing all the wlan0 configuration by eth0 in the tutorial, but then I don't have access to the wlan0 network. Is there a way to achieve both? Alternatively, I have a Apple's Airport Express wireless router, so if there is a way to configure the Pi so I can simply wire it to the Airport Express and then have the Express do the wireless, that would work too, but it does not seem to work when I follow the tutorial, and replace wlan0 by eth0. The code is all essentially the same as in the tutorial linked here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by simply adding a static_ip eth0 to dhcpcd.conf file and then a dhcp-range for interface=eth0 in the dnsmasq.conf file, and finally adding the following two lines in the iptables.ipv4.nat file

```css
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
```

I was now able to have internet through ethernet as well Raspberry Pi's wireless chip.

Comment: hi, could you please elaborate more your answer, for newbies like me, thanks